# Middle element from a disjoint set of sorted intervals

Tags: number-theory, statistics, elementary-set-theory

We want to find the middle element in the given intervals of numbers.

> Suppose we are given a set with 3 intervals which are { [1, 10], [20, 30], [35, 40] }. (The intervals are always disjoint).
>
> If we combine all intervals we get 25 numbers which are given below:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
>   30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
>
> The answer is the middle element which is the 13th element which is 22.
>   So the answer is 22.
>
> But each of the intervals can be of range [1,1000000000].
>   Given the intervals is there any formula to calculate the middle
>   element.
>
> Note : If there are 'n' number of elements and 'n' is even the answer
>   can be the (n/2)th element.
>
> Example : if there are total four elements if we combine intervals
>   then the 2nd element is the
>                    answer

Comment: If you're considering just integers, then $\lfloor \frac{max + min}{2} \rfloor$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. A minor issue is there are $27$ elements in your example (i.e., $10 + 11 + 6 = 27$), not $25$ as you state. Thus, the middle element would be the $14$'th one, i.e., $23$.